# Shutting down a Java RMI server

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

1. When I launch the GUI, it starts a new thread.

   ```
   final Server myServer = new Server();
   final Thread t1 = new Thread(myServer, "T1");
   t1.start();
   ```
2. The GUI only has a button that will stop the thread upon clicking:

   ```
   final JButton btnStartServer = new JButton("Stop server");
   btnStartServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           myServer.stop();
       }
   });
   ```
3. The thread will create an object TrackingServiceImpl which is the Java RMI server. Thread itself looks like this:

   ```
   class Server implements Runnable {
       private volatile boolean exit = false;

       public void run() {

           try {
               TrackingService server1 = new TrackingServiceImpl();

               TrackingService serverInstance, stub = null;
               Registry registry = null;

               while (!exit) {
                   serverInstance = ((TrackingServiceImpl) server1).getInstance();
                   stub = (TrackingService) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject((TrackingService) serverInstance, 0);
                   registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(4444);
                   registry.bind("TrackingService", stub);
                   System.out.println("Tracking service has started at port " + 4444);
               }

               System.out.println("Server is stopping....");
               registry.unbind("TrackingService");
               UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(registry, false);
           } catch (Exception e) {

           }

       }

       public void stop() {
           exit = true;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now if I click on the button before connecting any client to the server, the code works. Clients won't be unable to connect to the server. However, if I let a client connect to the server, and then I click on the button, the client continues to be able to invoke methods on the server even though the server should already have stopped (registry unbinded and exported).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"even though the server should already have stopped (registry unbinded and exported)."_ is this an assumption or a fact?

Comment: Does this  not stop it? 
registry.unbind("TrackingService");
UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(registry, false);

I mean it does it job not letting client connect if I stop the server before connecting any clients. However, if I stop it after connecting a client it doesn't seem to stop it, clients are still able to invoke methods.

Comment: @Teddy No, that unbinds it and stops the Registry. Nothing has stopped the remote object. Clients that already hold stubs can continue to call it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

None of this makes sense. Your code does not execute correctly. You don't need the loop or the `exit` variable, or the `Runnable` either, or the thread. Once the remote object is constructed, exported, and bound, it is available to clients for remote method calls. To stop it, just unbind it and unexport it with `UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject()`. NB At present you're only unexporting the Registry. There's no real need to do that.

Comment: I made it a thread because I want the GUI be able to start a Java RMI server and stop the current one running. Stopping the RMI server should not close my GUI. It does execute, please read my last point in the thread.

Comment: You don't need a thread to start a registry or export a remote object, as they aren't blocking operations, and you don't need a loop either. Your code loops forever throwing ignored `ExportExceptions`.

Comment: Tried unexporting the stub but it says stub hasn't been exported. Any ideas?
stub  = (TrackingService) UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject((TrackingService) serverInstance, 0);

Comment: I didn't say anything about unexporting the stub. I said to unexport the *object*. The remote object. NB That's not the real code. `unexportObject()` doesn't return a stub.